# Javascript non-blocking scripts, why don't simply put all scripts before </body> tag?

Tags: javascript, nonblocking, deferred-loading

**In order to avoid javascript to block webpage rendering, can't we just put all all our JS files/code to be loaded/executed simply before the closing `</body>` tag?**

All JS files and code would be downloaded and executed only after the all page has being rendered, so what's the need for tricks like the one suggested in this article about **[non blocking techniques to load JS files](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/)**. He basically suggests to use code like:

`document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);`

in order to defer script laod while letting the webpage to be rendered, thus resulting in fast rendering speed of the webpage.

But **without using this type of non-blocking technique (or other similar techniques)**, wouldn't we achieve the same non-blocking result by simply placing all our JS files (to be loaded/executed) before the closing `</body>` tag?

I'm even more surprised because the author (in the same article) suggests to put his code before the closing `</body>` tag (see the "Script placement" section of the article), so he is basically loading the scripts before the closing `</body>` tag anyway. What's the need for his code then?

I'm confused, any help appreciated, thanks!

---

UPDATE

FYI Google Analytics is using similar non-blocking technique to load their tracking code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
(function() 
{
   var ga = document.createElement('script');
   ga.type = 'text/javascript';
   ga.async = true;
   ga.src = 'your-script-name-here.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); //why do they insert it before the 1st script instead of appending to body/head could be the hint for another question.
})();
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

**If you want asynchonous scripts.**
Use the (HTML5) async tag if it is availble in the browser you're in. This is what Google Analytics is doing in the code you posted (specifically the line `ga.async = true` [MDN Link, scroll down for async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)).

However, this can cause your script to load at arbitrary times during the page load - which might be undesirable. It's worth asking yourself the following questions before choosing to use async.

**Don't need user input?** Then using the async attribute.

**Need to respond to buttons or navigation?** Then you need to put them at the top of the page (in head) and not use the async tag.

Async scripts run in any order, so if your script is depending on (say) jQuery, and jQuery is loaded in another tag, your script might run before the jQuery script does - resulting in errors.

---

**Why *don't* people put things at the bottom of the body tag?** If the script is taking enough time to load that it's slowing/pausing the load of the website, it's quite possible that that script is going to pause/hang the website after the website has loaded (expect different behaviour on different browsers) - making your website appear unresponsive (click on a button and nothing happens). In *most* cases this is not ideal, which is why the async attribute was invented.

---

Alternatively if your script is taking a long time to load - you might want to (after testing) **minify** and **concatenate** your script before sending it up to the server.

I recommend using [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) for minifying and concatenation, it's easy to get running and to use.

**Minifying** reduces the amount of data that needs to be downloaded.

**Concatenating** scripts reduces the number of "round-trips" to the server (for a far away server with 200ms ping, 5 requests takes 1 second).

Answer (score 1):

Generally saying no. Even if scripts will be loaded after all the content of the page, loading and executing of the scripts will block the page. The reason for that is possibility of presence of write commands in your scripts.

However if all you want to achieve is the speed of loading page contents, the result of placing script tags right before `</body>` tag is the same as for creating script tags dynamically. The most significant difference is that when you load scripts in common static way they are executed one by one, in other words no parallel execution of script file (in old browsers the same true is for downloading of the script too).

Comment: thanks for your answer. Couple of things: 1) you say: `...possibility of presence of write commands in your scripts.` Well but document.write command are not an option if script is executed after the page was rendered cause it would delete all the HTML page contents. And even loading script via a non-blocking technique would not allow us to use document.write command cause the script would still be executed after page was rendered.

Comment: 2) Are you sure that using non-blocking technique, scripts are loaded in parallel? I wonder what happens if scriptB uses scriptA, but scriptB is loaded and executed before scriptA?!

Comment: @Marco — it is *because* you can't use document.write in a non-blocking script that the script is non-blocking!

Comment: @Quentin: isn't is what I'm saying?! I don't underestand. From my understanding `document.write` can not be used in any case if we want to load and execute scripts after page was rendered. So it can't be the reason for choosing between using a non-blocking technique like the one suggested in the article vs simply placing the script before the </body> tag. What I mean is that `document.write` has got nothing to do here. Pls correct me if I missed something here.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of asynchronous loading (especially with something like the analytics snippet) is, at least if you would place it on the top, that it would be loaded as soon as possible without costing any time in rendering the page. So with analytics the chances to actually track a user before he leaves the page (maybe before the page was fully loaded) will be higher.

And the insertBefore is used instead of append, because if I remember correctly there was a bug (I think in some IE versions, see also link below theres something in the comments about that).

For me this link:
[Async JS](http://friendlybit.com/js/lazy-loading-asyncronous-javascript/)
was the most useful I found so far. Especially because it also brings up the issue, that even with googles analytic code the onload event will still be blocked (at least in some browsers). If you want this to not happen, better attach the function to the onload event.

For putting the asynchronous snippet on the bottom, that is actually explained in the link you posted. He seems to just do it to make sure that the DOM is completely loaded without using the onload event. So it may depend on what you're scripts are doing, if you're not manipulating the DOM there should be no reason for adding it on the bottom of body. Besides that, I personally would prefer adding it to the onload-event anyway.